Large number reading issue in karate
I have a json file which has the following java long inside,
 [
   {
      "large_num": 6168465146545
   }
 ]

When I call read method to that file: * def data = read("my-file.json"), it returns an error:
js failed:
>>>>
01: read("my-file.json")
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: js failed:
>>>>
.....
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: java.lang.AssertionError
- com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.HostToGuestRootNode.execute(HostToGuestRootNode.java:125)
- org.graalvm.polyglot.Value.as(Value.java:1642)
.....

The issue disappears, when smaller number (java int) are used.
I'm on v1.5.0.RC3

sounds like a Graal JS bug :( see if RC4 works else open an issue

If you are using JavaScript why the Java tag?

@aled I'm using Java

@PeterThomas Did not work with with RC4 as well (
